# In Bitcoin source, what is the UniValue objects purpose?

Tags: bitcoin-core, development, bitcoin-core-development, wallet-development

In the bitcoin source code you can see a lot of objects of type `UniValue`, particularly in the `miner.cpp` and `rpc/mining.cpp`. What is the utility of this `UniValue` object? Is it used to update the blockchain, or simply to return a message to a miner in their console?

Answer (score 5):

UniValue is a type that encapsulates a JSON value.

It is only used for communication with external utilities through the RPC interface.

Comment: Thanks, what do you mean by `external utilities`

Comment: Anything that wants to communicate with Bitcoin Core.